# "Exception calling 'GetFullPath'..." error when calling Scaffold-DbContext in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Professional to create an ASP.NET Core web site. I have a DLL that contains my Entity Framework Core models. I am using a Database First approach. Recently, when I try to call `Scaffold-DbContext` to update my models after adding a new database table, I get the following error:

```
Scaffold-DbContext : Exception calling "GetFullPath" with "1" argument(s): "The path is not of a legal form."
At line:1 char:1
+ Scaffold-DbContext "Server=[Server Name];Database=DB_TH_Cust ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Scaffold-DbContext], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException,Scaffold-DbContext
```

Here is the command I use:

> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=[Server URL];Database=DB_TH_Custom_Apps_Dev_SQL;Trusted_Connection=True;Column Encryption Setting=enabled" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Project "Data Layer" -Force

I don't understand what this error message means; I'm not sure exactly what path it's referring to or why it's not of a legal form (or even what a "legal form" would be in this context).

This is at least somewhat intermittent, and I don't know what changed to start this happening.

Closing and re-opening Visual Studio sometimes seems to help, but I'm not sure exactly when or why it helps. Recently, I had opened it running it as an administrator and received the error. I closed Visual Studio and re-opened it as an administrator and got the same error message again. I tried closing it and re-opening it a second time, except *not* as an administrator that time, and it worked. I'm not sure if that was what made the difference, and I'm not sure why that would matter. (If that *is*, in fact, the problem, I'd definitely be interested to know why).

The only Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34337042/exception-calling-getfullpath-with-1-arguments-the-path-is-not-of-a-legal) I've found so far that has the same error message seems to have occurred in an entirely different context, so I'm not sure how to apply it to my situation.

I also have a vague memory of reading an article that said that this could be caused by compilation errors in your solution, but I don't remember where. In any case, though, my solution compiles just fine.

Can someone explain what this error message means and why it's happening? Is there anything I can do to prevent it?

Comment: Try to remove the space from the project name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same issue. Very frustrating. I finally was able to resolve this issue by changing the "Startup Project" in Solution Properties.

I figured this out by going through the documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell

I noticed that in the command line I was using I was not defining -StartupProject. Hope this helps Josh, or future folks who come across this thread via Googling the error message, like I did.